# Mocking models used in a Django view with arguments

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

For the life of me I cannot figure this out and I'm having trouble finding information on it.

I have a Django view which accepts an argument which is a primary key (e.g: URL/problem/12) and loads a page with information from the argument's model.

I want to mock models used by my view for testing but I cannot figure it out, this is what I've tried:

```
@patch('apps.problem.models.Problem',)
def test_search_response(self, problem, chgbk, dispute):
    problem(problem_id=854, vendor_num=100, chgbk=122)

    request = self.factory.get(reverse('dispute_landing:search'))
    request.user = self.user
    request.usertype = self.usertype

    response = search(request, problem_num=12)

    self.assertTemplateUsed('individual_chargeback_view.html')
```

However - I can never get the test to actually find the problem number, it's as if the model does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because if you mock the entire model itself, the model **won't** exist because any of the functions to create/save it will have been mocked. If `Problem` is just a mock model class that hasn't been modified in any way, it knows nothing about interacting with the database, the ORM, or anything that could be discoverable from within your search() method.

One approach you could take rather than mocking models themselves would be to create FactoryBoy model factories. Since the test database is destroyed with each test run, these factories are a great way to create test data:

http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

You could spin up a ProblemFactory like so:

```
class ProblemFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = Problem

    problem_id = factory.Faker("pyint")
    vendor_num = factory.Faker("pyint")
    chgbk = factory.Faker("pyint")
```

Then use it to create a model that actually exists in your database:

```
def test_search_response(self, problem, chgbk, dispute):
    problem = ProblemFactory(problem_id=854, vendor_num=100, chgbk=122)

    request = self.factory.get(reverse('dispute_landing:search', kwargs={'problem_id':problem.id}))
    request.user = self.user
    request.usertype = self.usertype

    response = search(request, problem_num=854)

    self.assertTemplateUsed('individual_chargeback_view.html')
```